# Actualizar controles WPF dentro de un WinForms con ElementHost

Tags: c#

tengo un proyecto en Winform, el cuál ya no podemos migrar a WPF, por motivos de tiempo, tan sólo queremos que uno de los formularios esté en WPF por motivos de adaptabilidad a diferentes resoluciones.

El tema es que he creado un control de usuario WPF, y uso ElementHost para mostrarlo en un winform.

Al abrir la ventana me lo muestra sin problemas,a diferentes resoluciones como era la idea.(responsive). Pero cuando actualizo sus controles( textbox,label, etc) no se me actualizan en la ventana, he probado con usercontrol1.update(); y nada, volviendo a mostrar la ventana y aunque me salga la misma ventana por segunda vez no me sale actualizada.

Edito: Dejo mi codigo simplificado para aclarar( **userControl.xaml** es mi WPF con los datos a mostrar y **MarcadorWPF.cs** es mi winForm con el elemenHost incustrado) **panelControl.cs** es desde yo mando los datos actualizados.

**UserControl.xaml**

```
 public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void cargarDatos(String escudoLocal, String escudoVisit, String puntosLocal, String puntosVisit, String nomLocal, String nomVisit)
    {
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.BeginInit();
        bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(@escudoLocal, UriKind.Absolute);
        bitmapImage.EndInit();
        mImagenLocal.Source = bitmapImage;

        mTxtPuntosLocal.Text = puntosLocal;
        mTxtPuntosVisit.Text = puntosVisit;
        mTxtNomLocal.Text = nomLocal.ToUpper();
        mTxtNomVisit.Text = nomVisit.ToUpper();
    }
```

**panelControl.cs**

```
 public PanelControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();     
    }
private void btnEnviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Equipo equipo = new Equipo();                 
        UserControl1 userControl1 = new UserControl1();
        MarcadorWPF marcadorWPF = new MarcadorWPF();
        userControl1.cargarDatos(pictureBoxLocal.ImageLocation, pictureBoxVisit.ImageLocation, txtLocalPunto.Text, txtVisitPunto.Text, equipo.getNomEquipo(), mTxtNomVisit.Text);
        userControl1.setCrono(txtCrono.Text);
        userControl1.setPointLocal(txtLocalPunto.Text);
        marcadorWPF.Show();
        btnEnviar.Focus();
    }
```

**marcadorWPF.cs**

En principio no tiene nada, ya que lo uso para mostrar el WPF incrustado

**EDITO 2:** He realizado algo mucho más simple para descubrir el problema.
1. He realizado un nuevo proyecto : integracionWPF.
2. He creado un Un form con un elemenHost que incrusta un WPF que se llama usuarioControl1.
3. He creato un textbox en mi WPF( userControl1.xaml) y un boton en el Form
4. Al pulsar el boton del Form debe aparecer HOLA MUNDO en mi WPF. PERO TAMPOCO FUNCION

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace IntegracionWPF
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UserControl1 userControl1 = new UserControl1();
            userControl1.setText();
        }
    }
}
```

**userControl1.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace IntegracionWPF
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void setText()
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Hola Mundo";
        }
    }
}
```

Alguna idea de cuál es el problema? El control TextBox1 no se actualiza

Comment: cuando dices "actualizo sus controles" quieres decir que le asignas un contenido a los textbox del control creado en wpf ? si es asi como accedes al textbox que esta dentro, proque entiendo que de forma directa no puedes hacerlo

Comment: implementas en el control wpf algun patron como ser MVVM ?

Comment: userControl1.xaml tiene controles (textbox,label,etc) con un metodo public void cargarDatos(String escudoLocal, String escudoVisit, String puntosLocal, String puntosVisit, String nomLocal, String nomVisit)
        {
            mTxtPuntosLocal.Text = puntosLocal;
            mTxtNomVisit.Text = nomVisit.ToUpper();

Comment: Este metodo recibe los datos, pero si me dices que no se puede hacer así, como lo podría hacer?

Comment: Pregunta original editaba

Answer (score 1):

Como observaras en el articulo

[Integrate WPF UserControls in WinForms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26311/Integrate-WPF-UserControls-in-WinForms)

el control creado en wpf debes exponer alguna propiedad creada por ti para poder asignar el valor al control interno que este define.

En tu caso desde el control en wpf debes exponer

```
public void SetText(string text)
{
    textbox1.Text= text;
}
```

por supuesto si son varios textbox defines varios metodos.

Comment: Tengo 6 controles entre textbox,label y image, quieres decir que tengo que crear 6 métodos? no puede hacerse con un sólo metodo que reciba los 6 parametros? Gracias

Comment: claro, expones un metodo por cada control que quieras asignar el valor. Es mas puedes probarlo expone un control he intenta actualizarlo, si funciona entonces estas en el camino correcto y debes hacer lo mismo para el esto

Comment: He puesto en userControl1.cs esto y no se actualiza  public void setPointLocal(String puntosLocal)
        {
            mTxtPuntosLocal.Text = puntosLocal;
        }

Comment: He leido que hay que hacerlo con delegados, sabéis si se puede hacer sin estos?

Comment: cuando dices userControl1.cs es un control creado en WPF, no ? los delegados unidos a los eventos se utilizan en el caso inverso cuando quieres desde el control informar algo al form, entonces este se adjunta al evento para recibir notificaciones.Estas implementando algun patron como ser MVVM ?

Comment: Entonces me olvido de los delegados, No no uso un MVVM. UserControl es mi WPF que está dentro del elementHost de mi Winform

Comment: he editado nuevamente mi pregunta con un codigo mucho mas sencillo para probar, y tampoco funciona, serías tan amable de echarle un vistazo al código por si ves el problema. Gracias

Comment: Alguna nueva idea de porque no actualiza? He editado mi pregunta inicial al final.

Comment: Como comentario el botón que hace que cambie el contenido de los textBox del WPF está en un winForm, de ahi, el problema, si el boton estuviera en mi WPF no habría problema.